Combining Edit Cell and Edit Row from Antd Into one component
I managed to combine the code for both editing a cell and editing a row in the AntD table.
The Cell editing is working well.
The Row editing is not working at all.
First, when you click on edit, the current value disappears, and when you try to update the cell with a new value, it reverts back to the original value upon saving.
import React, { useContext, useRef, useState, useEffect } from "react";
import type { GetRef, InputRef, TableProps } from "antd";
import { Form, Input, InputNumber, Popconfirm, Table, Typography } from "antd";

// New Code for Cell Editing functionality
type FormInstance<T> = GetRef<typeof Form<T>>;
const EditableContext = React.createContext<FormInstance<any> | null>(null);

interface Item {
  key: string;
  name: string;
  age: number;
  address: string;
}

const originData: Item[] = [];
for (let i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
  originData.push({
    key: i.toString(),
    name: `Edward ${i}`,
    age: 32,
    address: `London Park no. ${i}`,
  });
}

interface EditableRowProps {
  index: number;
}

// New Code for Cell Editing functionality
const EditableRow: React.FC<EditableRowProps> = ({ index, ...props }) => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  return (
    <Form form={form} component={false}>
      <EditableContext.Provider value={form}>
        <tr {...props} />
      </EditableContext.Provider>
    </Form>
  );
};

interface EditableCellProps extends React.HTMLAttributes<HTMLElement> {
  index: number;
  title: any;

  // New Code for Cell Editing functionality
  cellEditable: boolean;
  handleCellSave: (record: Item) => void;

  editing: boolean;
  // dataIndex: string;
  dataIndex: keyof Item;
  inputType: "number" | "text";
  record: Item;

  isRowEditing: string | null;
}

const EditableCell: React.FC<React.PropsWithChildren<EditableCellProps>> = ({
  // New Code for Cell Editing functionality
  cellEditable,
  handleCellSave,

  editing,
  dataIndex,
  title,
  inputType,
  record,
  index,
  children,
  isRowEditing,
  ...restProps
}) => {
  // New Code for Cell Editing functionality
  const [editingCell, setEditingCell] = useState(false);
  // const inputRef = useRef<InputRef>(null);
  const inputRef = useRef<HTMLInputElement>(null);
  const inputNumberRef = useRef<any>(null);
  const form = useContext(EditableContext)!;

  useEffect(() => {
    if (editingCell) {
      inputRef.current?.focus();
    }
  }, [editingCell]);

  const toggleEdit = () => {
    console.log("toggleEdit", record[dataIndex]);
    setEditingCell(!editingCell);
    form.setFieldsValue({ [dataIndex]: record[dataIndex] });
  };

  const saveCell = async () => {
    if (!isRowEditing) {
      // Only proceed if the row is not in edit mode
      try {
        const values = await form.validateFields();
        toggleEdit();
        handleCellSave({ ...record, ...values });
      } catch (errInfo) {
        console.log("Save failed: from Save Cell", errInfo);
      }
    }
  };

  let childNode = children;

  const inputNode =
    inputType === "number" ? (
      <InputNumber ref={inputRef} onPressEnter={saveCell} onBlur={saveCell} />
    ) : (
      <Input ref={inputNumberRef} onPressEnter={saveCell} onBlur={saveCell} />
    );

  if (cellEditable || editing) {
    childNode =
      editingCell || editing ? (
        <Form.Item
          style={{ margin: 0 }}
          name={dataIndex}
          rules={[
            {
              required: true,
              message: `${title} is required.`,
            },
          ]}
        >
          {inputNode}
        </Form.Item>
      ) : (
        <div
          className="editable-cell-value-wrap"
          style={{ paddingRight: 24 }}
          onClick={toggleEdit}
        >
          {children}
        </div>
      );
  }

  return <td {...restProps}>{childNode}</td>;

  // End of New Code for Cell Editing functionality
};

const App: React.FC = () => {
  const [form] = Form.useForm();
  const [data, setData] = useState(originData);
  const [editingKey, setEditingKey] = useState("");
  console.log("=>(indexBothEditRowAndCell.tsx:150) editingKey", editingKey);
  const isEditing = (record: Item) => record.key === editingKey;
  console.log("=>(indexBothEditRowAndCell.tsx:151) isEditing", isEditing);

  const [isRowEditing, setIsRowEditing] = useState<string | null>(null);

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Current form values:", form.getFieldsValue());
  }, [editingKey, data, form]);

  const editRow = (record: Partial<Item> & { key: React.Key }) => {
    console.log("=>(indexBothEditRowAndCell.tsx:166) record", record);
    form.setFieldsValue({
      name: record.name,
      age: record.age,
      address: record.address,
      ...record,
    });
    console.log("Form Fields after setting values:", form.getFieldsValue()); // Debugging line to check form values after setting

    setEditingKey(record.key);
    setIsRowEditing(record.key);
  };

  const cancelSaveRow = () => {
    setEditingKey("");
    setIsRowEditing(null);
  };

  // const saveRow = async (key: string) => {
  //   try {
  //     console.log("Form Fields before validation:", form.getFieldsValue());
  //     const row = (await form.validateFields()) as Item;
  //     console.log("Row data after validation:", row);
  //
  //     const newData = [...data];
  //     console.log("=>(indexBothEditRowAndCell.tsx:179) newData", newData);
  //     const index = newData.findIndex((item) => key === item.key);
  //     console.log("=>(indexBothEditRowAndCell.tsx:181) index", index);
  //     const item = newData[index];
  //     console.log("=>(indexBothEditRowAndCell.tsx:183) item", item);
  //     newData.splice(index, 1, {
  //       ...item,
  //       ...row,
  //     });
  //     setData(newData);
  //     setEditingKey("");
  //     setIsRowEditing(null);
  //
  //     // if (index > -1) {
  //     //   const item = newData[index];
  //     //   newData.splice(index, 1, {
  //     //     ...item,
  //     //     ...row,
  //     //   });
  //     //   setData(newData);
  //     //   setEditingKey("");
  //     //   setIsRowEditing(null);
  //     // } else {
  //     //   newData.push(row);
  //     //   setData(newData);
  //     //   setEditingKey("");
  //     //   setIsRowEditing(null);
  //     // }
  //   } catch (errInfo) {
  //     console.log("Validate Failed: from Save Row", errInfo);
  //   }
  // };

  const saveRow = async (key: string) => {
    try {
      // Step 1: Log the form state before validation
      console.log("Form Fields before validation:", form.getFieldsValue());

      // Step 2: Validate form fields
      const values = await form.validateFields().catch((err) => {
        console.error("Validation Error:", err);
        throw err; // Re-throw to ensure we catch validation errors
      });

      // Step 3: Log the validated values
      console.log("Values after validation:", values);

      const newData = [...data];
      const index = newData.findIndex((item) => key === item.key);
      if (index === -1) {
        console.log("Item not found in data array.");
        return; // Early return if the item isn't found
      }
      const item = newData[index];

      // Update the data array with the new item values
      newData.splice(index, 1, { ...item, ...values });
      setData(newData);
      setEditingKey("");
      setIsRowEditing(null);
    } catch (errInfo) {
      console.log("Validate Failed: from Save Row", errInfo);
    }
  };

  const handleDelete = (key: React.Key) => {
    const newData = data.filter((item) => item.key !== key);
    setData(newData);
  };

  const handleCellSave = (row: Item) => {
    const newData = [...data];
    const index = newData.findIndex((item) => row.key === item.key);
    const item = newData[index];
    newData.splice(index, 1, {
      ...item,
      ...row,
    });
    setData(newData);
  };

  const columns = [
    {
      title: "name",
      dataIndex: "name",
      width: "25%",
      rowEditable: true,
      cellEditable: true,
    },
    {
      title: "age",
      dataIndex: "age",
      width: "15%",
      rowEditable: true,
      cellEditable: true,
    },
    {
      title: "address",
      dataIndex: "address",
      width: "40%",
      rowEditable: true,
    },
    {
      title: "operation",
      dataIndex: "operation",
      render: (_: any, record: Item) => {
        const isEditable = isEditing(record);
        return isEditable ? (
          <span>
            <Typography.Link
              onClick={() => saveRow(record.key)}
              style={{ marginRight: 8 }}
            >
              Save
            </Typography.Link>
            <Popconfirm title="Sure to cancel?" onConfirm={cancelSaveRow}>
              <a>Cancel</a>
            </Popconfirm>
          </span>
        ) : (
          <>
            <Typography.Link
              disabled={editingKey !== ""}
              onClick={() => editRow(record)}
            >
              Edit
            </Typography.Link>
            <Popconfirm
              title="Sure to delete?"
              onConfirm={() => handleDelete(record.key)}
            >
              <a>Delete</a>
            </Popconfirm>
          </>
        );
      },
    },
  ];

  const mergedColumns: TableProps["columns"] = columns.map((col) => {
    if (!col.rowEditable || !col.cellEditable) {
      return col;
    }
    return {
      ...col,
      onCell: (record: Item) => ({
        record,
        inputType: col.dataIndex === "age" ? "number" : "text",
        dataIndex: col.dataIndex,
        title: col.title,
        editing: isEditing(record),
        cellEditable: col.cellEditable,
        handleCellSave,
        isRowEditing: isRowEditing === record.key, // Pass whether the row is being edited
      }),
    };
  });

  return (
    <Form form={form} component={false}>
      <Table
        components={{
          body: {
            row: EditableRow,
            cell: EditableCell,
          },
        }}
        bordered
        dataSource={data}
        columns={mergedColumns}
        rowClassName="editable-row"
        pagination={{
          onChange: cancelSaveRow,
        }}
      />
    </Form>
  );
};

export default App;


I have tried everything that I can think of.
